# Checking if all non-NA elements between two or more columns or vectors are identical

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have two columns in a dataframe that contain date information after a left outer join. Because of the style of join, one of the date columns now contains NAs. I want to check if all non-NA values are identical between these columns. An example is below:

```
date 1     date 2
1/1/21     NA 
1/2/21     1/2/21
1/3/21     NA
1/4/21     1/4/21
```

I don't need the second column if all non-NA values match

Before I did the left outer join, I did a outer join and this statement:

```
identical(df[['date 1']], df[['date 2']])
```

returned a true as each row in both columns were indeed identical

Is there a way to use this or a similar statement while ignoring all rows that contain an "NA" in "date 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for null values and mismatched values by filtering your df, then check whether there are any.

```
df_mismatch = df[(df['date 2'].notnull()) & (df['date 1'] != df['date 2'])]

if len(df_mismatch) > 0:
    print('found this many mismatches:', len(df_mismatch))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

first, create a new dataframe that just stores these two columns. The reason you'll want to make a new dataframe is because we will use `na.omit` in the next step which will remove any row that contains 1 or more "NA" in any column.

```
df2 <- df[, c("date 1", "date2")]
```

Then remove all rows that contain an "NA" in any column

```
df2 <- na.omit(df2)
```

Finally, run `identical` to check if the remaining columns are indeed identical

```
identical(df2[['date1']], df2[['date2']])
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this worked for me in the meantime